# How to afford an expensive medical operation abroad from in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, loans, medical-tourism

I'm currently investigating ways of getting an expensive medical operation done in Spain. It's not something the NHS covers and after doing a lot of looking around I've decided that this is best option for me.

- Cost of the operation is averagely between £20,000 - £40000.
- They don't offer any kind of payment plan.

How should I go about affording such an operation? Apart from just saving for it in a lump sum?

My details (though I worry they make this question less generally helpful for others in future):

- I earn ~£35,000 a year.
- I have ~£10,000 in my account.
- I have a mortgage on a ~£250,000 home, of which I paid around a ~£100,000 deposit, and am 1 year into paying off at around ~£600 a month.
- I owe ~£3500 for furnishing my home which is being paid off over 2 years at around ~£150 a month.
- CreditClub rates my credit score at ~975.
- I've never owned a credit card.

I would really like to avoid a debate on whether or not I should get this operation done. I would just like some advice on how I should get it done.

Thanks

Comment: Apart from saving any other option is to loan it. There are places in UK that specialise in loans for medical purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Look for another country that offers "hospitalisation tourism" for your *expensive medical operation*, e.g. South Korea, Thailand, etc.
- (update on OP clarify the house mortgage repayment) You can re-mortgage your house with a new term. Since your current mortgage is 20 years, adding extra 20~40k is not going to increase the repayment a lot.  Look around for [flexible mortgage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_mortgage) , as this allows you pay back more money than the repayment scheme to reduce the interest.  Re-mortgage is always better options as the bank already assess most of the risk and with your house as collateral, so the interest is usually lower than an individual loan.
- Only arrange for a special medical loan unless the interest is lower
- check whether any tax writes off can be applied for the operation.

Comment: big problem with medical tourism in many countries is the quality of care. Too many people end up dead or with permanent medical problems as a result and the NHS isn't going to pay for any of that unless the damage was done by an NHS physician in the first place. As to paying off your mortgage with savings, that's often actually more expensive than not doing so as the penalties for early payment are in many cases excessively high.

Comment: @jwenting can you provide any citation that the NHS will abandon someone suffering complications from an elective surgery conducted outside of the NHS?  The NHS deals with such things all the time.  They might not pay for corrective surgery where the outcome is what you want, but they won’t let you suffer.

Comment: @jwenting  usually complete loan settlement penalty clause only applied to the first few years of the mortgage.

Comment: @mootmoot tell that to my bank...

Comment: @mootmoot I don't think I understand what your saying. I can't settle my entire mortgage with £10,000. There's still like £140,000 left to pay.

Comment: @HazelCheese you sentence say *"am 1 year into paying off "* is confusing. I just update the answer.

Comment: @mootmoot Ok thanks. This is a bit of an open question with no right answer I guess but I'm going to accept this one since it covers a few possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

You have more than 40% equity in your mortgage, so I would expect that the cheapest way for you to borrow would be to borrow more on that.

Either remortgage for a larger amount or your current provider may be willing to loan you more (e.g. https://www.nationwide.co.uk/products/mortgages/borrowing-more/is-borrowing-more-right-for-you).

The important potential disadvantages to this are that the debt is secured to your house (probably not a major concern as you seem in pretty good financial shape), and that you probably don't want to spread the cost of the operation over the full term of the mortgage (otherwise you will pay a lot of interest even if at a lower annual rate).

Comment: Aren't mortgage offers made knowing what you can afford? Why would they allow me to remortgage 1 year later for a higher repayment amount when they could of done that in the first place?

Comment: If you maxed out the affordability in the first place, then maybe.  If nothing else they may be happy to loan back the repayments you have made and/or extend the repayment period.  The fact you have paid reliably and are only borrowing 60% are in your favour.  No harm in asking.

Answer (score 0):

Many private hospitals and doctors will negotiate a payment plan for an expensive operation. To go this route in the UK you would have to have the operation by a [private doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_medicine_in_the_United_Kingdom).

In Spain, I assume it is similar in that you would just need to find a hospital that can do the operation and is willing to negotiate a payment plan. One issue is that they may be reluctant to extend credit to a foreign national.

If you cannot find a hospital that will agree to a payment plan, you can borrow the money. Don't use a credit card. Just go to a bank and make a personal loan application. If your credit is not good enough to get the loan, there is the possibility to get a third party to co-sign the loan for you. Note that the terms of a hospital will be way better than a bank, so you are far better off finding a hospital that will agree to payments than borrowing from a bank.